# Issue understanding error messages given to me (Starting C++/programming)

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out in C++ and programming languages in general, so I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the error messages I am given.

I am writing a program that converts `Fahrenheit` to `celcius`. I believe my code is correct or close to correct, however I am receiving error messages. My code is below

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void f2c(void) {
    // (a) Prompt user to enter value.

    // (b) Declare local variable to hold input value.

    // (c) Read input value.

    // (d) Compute output value.

    // (e) Display the result.
    }


    int main(void) {
    float celcius;
    float fahrenheit;
    f2c();

    printf("\n Enter temperature in fahrenheit:");
    scanf("%lf",&fahrenheit);
    celcius=(fahrenheit-32)*5/9;
    printf("Temperature in celcius is %lf:",celcius);

    return 0;
    }
```

I am receiving this error message when attempting to compile

```
f2c.c: In function ‘main’:
f2c.c:22:11: error: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Werror=format=]
     scanf("%lf",&fahrenheit);
           ^
```

```
f2c.c:22:11: error: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Werror=format=]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double \*’, but argument 2 has type ‘float \*’"  Your scanf says %lf but you give it &fahrenheit, which is a pointer to float, not pointer to double -- just like the error message says.   You can either switch it to %f or change fahrenheit from float to double.   The message is telling you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: Note that this is C code. While it is valid C++ code, it would not be written this way in idiomatic C++.

Comment: Are you learning C++ or C? You say you're learning C++, but your code looks like C. In C++, you should use the facilities in the `<iostream>` header, which are easier to use than the C I/O functions.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate variable for the format string %lf is `double *`, not `float *`.

A list of format string parameters and associated variable types is presented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f2c(void) {
// (a) Prompt user to enter value.

// (b) Declare local variable to hold input value.

// (c) Read input value.

// (d) Compute output value.

// (e) Display the result.
}


int main(void) {
float celcius;
double fahrenheit; // <== CHANGE THIS LINE
f2c();

printf("\n Enter temperature in fahrenheit:");
scanf("%lf",&fahrenheit);
celcius=(fahrenheit-32)*5/9;
printf("Temperature in celcius is %lf:",celcius);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to research the list

Comment: @Thrillhouse [Bookmark this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). Go there and you'll understand why. It's hands-down the best C and C++ reference site on the web.

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree but in this case I think the wikipedia page is more geared towards the level of question this is.  cppreference can be hard to follow for new C++ programmers.